# How can I crop an image to have curved irregular edges?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

I have UITableViewCell with image in the right size.
This is how the cell should look like:
[image]

And i have the backgound:
[image]

And the image placeholder:
[image]

And i want to know if there is a way to crop image with the iOS library?

Comment: Turn the white area inside the image placeholder to transparent, then locate the image view under that image. No, there is no such system library. PS: the artwork looks nice!

Comment: You should ask questions of the style: `Here is my problem, here is my attempted solution, what is wrong with my solution` ***NOT*** `Here is my problem, write the solution for me`. [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: @DavidH, not true, there is a Core Graphics function that will do it. Still want to see what MTA tried though. Note, this isn't a crop operation - it's a clipping / masking operation.

Comment: @Wain thanks for the info, i will check it and post a question with code that i tried on my project.

Comment: No need for a new question, we have a perfectly good one here :)

Comment: @Wain my point was there is no HIGH level library to do this. For sure you can do anything using Quartz and CoreGraphics but many people on this site have difficulty doing so. I think using a "stack" of views, were one has a transparent center, will be the easiest to implement. YMMV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that possible:

```
UIImage *imageToCrop = ...;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext();
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[imageToCrop drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, CGRectMake(0 ,0, imageToCrop.size.width,  imageToCrop.size.height);
CGContextClip(context);
UIImage *croppedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CoreGraphics to add mask or clip with path. Mask is image with alpha channel which determines what part of image show. Below example how clip with image mask:

```
- (UIImage *)croppedImage:(UIImage *)sourceImage
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(width, height), NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextClipToMask(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), [UIImage imageNamed:@"mask"].CGImage);

    [sourceImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height)];

    UIImage *resultImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return resultImage;
}
```

Then you can write `cell.picture = [self croppedImage:sourceImage];`

Answer (score 0):

You can use image masking technique to crop this image
Please have a look at this link 
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_images/dq_images.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH212-CJBHIJEB

I have written some code that may help you out

```
@interface ImageRenderer : NSObject {
UIImage *image_;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage * image;
- (void)cropImageinRect:(CGRect)rect;
- (void)maskImageWithMask:(UIImage *)maskImage;
- (void)imageWithAlpha;
@end

@implementation ImageRenderer

@synthesize image = image_;

- (void)cropImageinRect:(CGRect)rect  {
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(image_.CGImage, rect);
image_ = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
}

- (void)maskImageWithMask:(UIImage *)maskImage  {

CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGImageRef maskImageRef = [maskImage CGImage];
// create a bitmap graphics context the size of the image
CGContextRef mainViewContentContext = CGBitmapContextCreate (NULL, maskImage.size.width, maskImage.size.height, 8, 0, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
if (mainViewContentContext == NULL){
    return;
   }

CGFloat ratio = 0;

ratio = maskImage.size.width/ image_.size.width;

if(ratio * image_.size.height < maskImage.size.height) {
    ratio = maskImage.size.height/ image_.size.height;
} 

CGRect rect1  = {{0, 0}, {maskImage.size.width, maskImage.size.height}};
CGRect rect2  = {{-((image_.size.width*ratio)-maskImage.size.width)/2 , -((image_.size.height*ratio)-maskImage.size.height)/2}, {image_.size.width*ratio, image_.size.height*ratio}};

CGContextClipToMask(mainViewContentContext, rect1, maskImageRef);
CGContextDrawImage(mainViewContentContext, rect2, image_.CGImage);
// Create CGImageRef of the main view bitmap content, and then
// release that bitmap context
CGImageRef newImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(mainViewContentContext);
CGContextRelease(mainViewContentContext);

image_ = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newImage];

CGImageRelease(newImage);
}

- (void)imageWithAlpha {
CGImageRef imageRef = image_.CGImage;
CGFloat width = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
CGFloat height = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);

CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef context =  CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, width, height, 8, 0, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageRef);

CGImageRef resultImageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
image_ = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:resultImageRef scale:image_.scale orientation:image_.imageOrientation];

CGContextRelease(context);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
CGImageRelease(resultImageRef);
}

@end
```

In this code you can crop the image out of a bigger one and then you can use a mask image to get your work done.